# Select latest selected value of a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to select the latest user's selected value of a dropdown?

Eg:

```
<select id="data" name="data" class="data" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="100">foo</option>
    <option value="101">bar</option>
    <option value="102">bat</option>
    <option value="103">baz</option>
</select>
```

If I use something like the bellow example, what I get is the last index, but it's not what I want.

```
var latest_value = $("option:selected:last",this).val();
```

What I want is something like: if you select "bar", I get 101, if you select "foo" I get 101 instead of 100.

OBS: all my examples are considering that the user is selecting multiple values, not just one.

Comment: Wouldn't simply getting the html or text of the selected option on change be what you want?

Comment: I've tryied the following: $('#data').change(function(){$(this).val() }) and I receive the whole array of selected values. EDIT: changed my example, because I want the value, not the text.

Comment: How are you getting the value? By that I mean, what event are you using? Also, since you have the multiple attribute set, how did you want to handle that? And the code you posted gets the last clicked on value: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1yfp1sv1/

Comment: About the fiddle, no. If you select foo and bar it'll give the whole array to you. About the event, I'm using the change, when the user select the next element, it will be handled by the change. My aplication always select another value it never selects just one.

Comment: The code I posted on comment get the whole array, I want just the 100, because foo was the latest value selected. Try it by selecting bar, then foo (you must select both)

Answer (score 2):

Use this simple js code:

```
var is_now_selected = document.getElementById('data').value;

// or with jQuery

var is_now_selected = $('#data').val()
```

Maybe you don't know that the `option`-value accually is the value of the `select`. If you click `<option value="something">` which is inside a `<select name="select_me">`, then this select will have the value of the selected `option` - in this case - `"select_me"`.

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I want. I edited my question, maybe you can understand better my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code. It may help you.

Please let me know if you have anymore problem.

```
$("#data").change(function () {
    alert($("#data").val());
});
```